# Gráficas con Highcharts y PHP

Tags: php, sql, highcharts

Realizo gráficas con Higcharts, lo que realiza mi sentencia es que hace un conteo con el campo `priority_id` y los agrupa según la fecha creada `MONTHNAME(created_at) y la prioridad (priority_id)`.

El problema que tengo es que en mis barras de la gráfica solo me muestra el mes de la fecha a la que pertenece y necesito que me muestre el mes y la prioridad justamente en esta linea es donde toma el valor del campo y se visualiza en la gráfica.

```
['<?php echo $res['MONTHNAME(created_at)']   ?>'],
```

Saludos.

```html
<?php 
                $sql=mysql_query("SET lc_time_names = 'es_MX'");
       $sql=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(created_at) AS total , t.priority_id, p.name, MONTHNAME(created_at) FROM ticket t INNER JOIN priority p ON t.priority_id = p.id GROUP BY  t.priority_id, MONTHNAME(created_at) order by MONTHNAME(created_at) DESC");
       while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
       ?>
  
  
                ['<?php echo $res['MONTHNAME(created_at)']   ?>'],
       
  
  
  <?php
```

[image: Gráfica, solo muestra los nombres de los meses pero necesito que muestre: Junio, PUEDO TRABAJAR]
[image: Resultado sentencia SQL]

Comment: Intenta con `['<?php echo $res['MONTHNAME(created_at)'] . " " . $res['priority_id']  ?>'],`

Comment: @alanfcm Muchas gracias por tu aporte me funciono.